# Delay start of jQuery rotators, one second apart from each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, rotator

I have three rotators on the front page and I'd like them to start 1 second after each other.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rot_top').cycle({       
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 2000
    });
    $('#rot_mid').cycle({       
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 2000
    });
    $('#rot_btm').cycle({       
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 2000
    });
});
```

after the initial start - they should proceed according to their regular timeout.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: You can make your code more readable by putting four spaces before it,  this will make it syntax highlighted as well. And welcome to Stackoverflow! +1 because your new!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)?  If so, there's a `delay` option which delays only the first change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rot_top').cycle({           
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 2000
    });
    $('#rot_mid').cycle({           
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 2000,
        delay: 1000,
    });
    $('#rot_btm').cycle({           
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 2000
        delay: 2000,
    });
});
```

This will start the first cycle immediately, the second cycle a second later, and the third cycle a second after that.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is pretty useful for this, give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  startCycle = function({
    $('#rot_top').cycle({speed: 500, timeout: 2000 }); 
    $('#rot_mid').cycle({speed: 500, timeout: 2000 }); 
    $('#rot_btm').cycle({speed: 500, timeout: 2000 }); 
  })

  setTimeout(startCycle();, 1000)
});
```

Comment: I think this would cause all three rotators to start at the same time.